# Highchart data each row on gridview to display different data on button click open modal

Tags: javascript, c#, html, highcharts

I have a **gridview** in ASP.NET with a **asp:templatefield** containing a button for each row. On the button I have a data-target attribute which is a modal.

On gridview row bound I am getting the ID of the row and calling the method **SerializedBoxChart()** which puts in the ID of the row and retrieves the data. However, it looks like it loops through each row and i end up with the last row's data on each row of the gridview. When i click on the button it opens the modal with the final row data. I am trying to assign the data for each row depending on the measureID and when you click on the button it opens up with that rows data.

I have a feeling its to do with conflicting IDs on the container when highcharts javascript is running the script and placing it in the div but dont know how to fix this.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AvgDaysTaken" SortExpression="AvgDaysTaken">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button type="button" runat="server" id="AvgDaysTaken" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myBoxPlot"  Text='<%# Eval("AvgDaysTaken") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Modal code which contains a div with ID container where the graph will be placed

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myBoxPlot" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div id="container" >
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Get the data for the box plot using c#

```
 public void SerializedBoxChart(int measureid)
{

    string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].so", cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTeamNo", SubTeam);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", Month);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Year);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportPeriod", ReportPeriod);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlID", ControlID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PracticeGroupID", PracticeGroup);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Instructor", SearchInput.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeasureID", measureid) ;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    var chartValues = new List<string>();
    var chartValues2 = new List<string>();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string name = reader.GetString(0);

            if (name != "Total")
            {


                string str = reader["ChartData"].ToString();
                string a = reader["MeasureDesc"].ToString();

                string[] strList = str.Split(',');

                // convert it in json
                dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strList, Formatting.None);

                hiddenvariable.Value = dataStr;
                hiddenvariablemeasuredesc.Value = a;

                chartValues.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {

    }

    reader.Close(); // close the reader
    cn.Close();



}
```

The javascript for creating the box plot:

```
function CreateBoxPlot() {


    var hv = $('#hiddenvariable').val();
console.log(hv);
var hvmeasure = $('#hiddenvariablemeasuredesc').val();
console.log(hvmeasure);

var chart;
var titleText = hvmeasure;
var subTitleText = 'Test Chart Subtitle';
var type = 'boxplot';
var data = [JSON.parse(hv).map(item => parseInt(item))]; //Doesnt work in IE

var $container = $('<div>').appendTo(document.body);

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { type: type, inverted: true},
        title: { text: hvmeasure },
        subtitle: { text: subTitleText },
        renderTo: $container[0],
        legend: { enabled: false },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 50
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            visible: false

        },
        yAxis: {

            visible: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Values'
            },

            plotLines: [{
                value: 80,
                color: 'red',
                width: 2

            }]

        }
    });

    chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.addSeries({ data: data });

 });
}
```

Comment: Hi RA19, You used a `highcharts` tag, but the problem is more related with your back-end code. I can recommend you Highcharts `.NET` wrapper: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/products/dotnet/ or I can help you, but only with JS code.

Comment: I can try work on .Net wrapper but is it possible to do this in JS? Please help on how?

Comment: Hi @RA19, Unfortunately I do not quite understand your concept, because I do not know `C#` language. If you provide me with the hard-coded data and description what exactly you want to achieve in JS, I will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ever solve this?

I'm guessing you did not post all of your code, or you edited it, leaving information out.

In the `SerializedBoxChart` method, you create two (2) `List<String>` variables. One **chartValues** is cleared after every pass through your `while loop` while the other one **chartValues2** is never used.

I suspect this is the data you were attempting to keep.

Instead of saving this information in temporary `List<String>` variables, you need an HTML list on your page that you can send data to.

If you had storage locations on your HTML page, like `listView1` and `listView2`, your code would be like this:

```cs
public void SerializedBoxChart(int measureid) {

    var list1 = (ListView)FindControl("listView1");
    var list2 = (ListView)FindControl("listView2");

    if ((list1 != null) && (list2 != null)) {
        string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var chartValues = new List<string>();
        var chartValues2 = new List<string>();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].cr_fe_KPI_RPT_Summary", new SqlConnection(connectionstring))) {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTeamNo", SubTeam);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", Month);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Year);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportPeriod", ReportPeriod);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlID", ControlID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PracticeGroupID", PracticeGroup);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Instructor", SearchInput.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeasureID", measureid);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                if (reader.HasRows) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        string name = reader.GetString(0);
                        if (name != "Total") {
                            string str = reader["ChartData"].ToString();
                            string a = reader["MeasureDesc"].ToString();

                            chartValues.Add(str);
                            chartValues2.Add(a);

                            string[] strList = str.Split(',');

                            // convert it in json
                            var dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strList, Formatting.None);

                            hiddenvariable.Value = dataStr;
                            hiddenvariablemeasuredesc.Value = a;

                        }
                    }
                }
                // reader.Close(); don't need to close in a USING statement
            }
        }
        list1.DataSource = chartValues;
        list1.DataBind();
        list2.DataSource = chartValues2;
        list2.DataBind();
    }
}
```